# Two-way lookup in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel with some data. In this I have fill the time by matching date and employee's name. I have tried to use this formula but it shows error. Kindly, help me on this.

```
=INDEX(L:R,MATCH(U3&V3,L:L&N:N,0),7)
```

Comment: have you tried `ctrl+shift+enter` when finishing the formula, rater than just `enter`?

Answer (score 3):

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

For an array-free version that can be confirmed with just the Enter key, try

```
=INDEX(L:R,MATCH(U5&V5,INDEX(L:L&N:N,0),0),7)
```

In either situation, array or non array formula, I strongly advise to refrain from using whole column references. They will calculate for over a million cells for each column. The formula will be much faster if you can ringfence the number of rows used, for example for 100 rows of data (adjust to your needs accordingly, but anything will be faster than whole columns):

```
=INDEX($L$1:$R$100,MATCH(U5&V5,INDEX($L$1:$L$100&$N$1:$N$100,0),0),7)
```

Comment: For same formula i am getting result for some rows.

Comment: you need to understand that Match only finds the first match. If that is not what you need, EDIT YOUR QUESTION and provide a data sample with some context.